# python pandas merge/vlookup tables

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, lookup

I was writing the Python code below to merge two tables, which could be done in Excel using Vlookup, but wanted to automate this process for a larger data set. However, it seems the output data is too big and contains all columns from both tables. I just wanted to use the second table, df_pos to lookup some columns. Would you take a look if my code is efficient or feasible to perform this task?

Thank you!

```
def weighted(mwa="mwa.csv",mwa2="mwa.csv",output="WeightedMWA.csv"):
    df=pd.read_csv(mwa, thousands=",")
    df['Keyword']=df['Keyword'].replace('+','')
    df_pos=pd.read_csv("mwa.csv", thousands=",")
    df_pos['Keyword']=df_pos['Keyword'].replace('+','')
    sumImp=df_pos['Impr.'].sum()
    sumPos=df_pos.groupby(by=['Keyword'])['Avg. Pos.'].sum()
    df_pos['WeightedPos']=sumPos/sumImp
    mergedDF=pd.merge(left=df, right=df_pos, how="left", left_on="Keyword",right_on="Keyword")
    mergedDF.to_csv(output)
```

Comment: I think this is best suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I haven't used Stackoverflow, I will do this next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide us with enough information.  You are outputting the merged dataframe but you have not told up which columns are necessary in the output.  Ideally, you'd want to keep only the columns that are needed in the output plus the columns needed for the merge.

You can limit the columns that you import via the `read_csv` function and its `usecols` parameter.  The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) says:

> ```
> usecols : array-like, default None
>     Return a subset of the columns. All elements in this array must either
>     be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings
>     that correspond to column names provided either by the user in `names` or
>     inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a valid `usecols`
>     parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']. Using this parameter
>     results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.
> ```

Comment: Yeap, since this contains the real data, couldn't display all names of columns and so on. But will try this and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @prodirector did that fix your issue?

Comment: Hi I've added this 'usecols', but I guess I have to fix the merging part first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using `df_pos` to lookup data from another matrix, just use the field in `df_pos` as an index to the frame you're looking up data from, i.e. datasourcematrix[df_pos.LOOKUPCOLUMNNAME] or if you don't have a column name, you can do datasourcematrix[df_pos.ix[5]] or whatever.  Much easier and faster...

Comment: Thank you I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: So, basically the datasource and lookup data are the same files, I tried:     mergedDF=df[df_pos.Keyword]
 but the result says, KeyError: "['cereal coupons' 'cereal coupons' 'cereal coupons' ...,\n 'baby care discount' 'baby care discount' 'baby care discount'] not in index".

Comment: Yeah so your DataFrame indexes don't use those names, try the ix[5] method until you find the right index.  Cycle through 0-end.  If you use Spyder IDE it lets you open the DataFrame easily in the variable explorer

Comment: So I kept trying this method, the result gives me an error, ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. Does this mean I have NA values in the index column? I actually don't have any NA values, wonder if this has been caused because I called the pd.read_csv in a wrong way?  df=pd.read_csv(mwa, thousands=",")
    df_pos=pd.read_csv(mwa2,usecols=['Keyword', 'Impr.', 'Avg. Pos.'],thousands=",")